# A sub manifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Riemannian?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth immersed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with or without boundary. I have been told that then $X$ is a Riemannian manifold. I was explained that this follows from Nash embedding theorem. But after looking it up it wasn't clear to me how this was the case. Any clarification on how the statement follows from Nash embedding theorem or explanation of other ways to see this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Riemann manifold and any submanifold has a natural metric which is the restriction of the ambient space metric. You can use this fact along with the Whitney embedding theorem (every manifold can be embedded in an $\mathbb{R}^n$) to prove every manifold has a Riemann metric

Comment: Thank you.  Since I am starting with a submanifold of $X$, I thought the conclusion follows from only the first part of your comment. or is this not the case?

Comment: yes if $X$ is already in an $(\mathbb{R}^n,g)$ in your case so you can assign it a metric $\tilde{g}$ which for $p\in X$ and $v_1,v_2\in T_pX$ is defined as $\tilde{g}(p)(v_1,v_2)=g(v_1,v_2)$. It's basically the same $g$ except it's defined only for points in $X$ and for vectors in the tangent space of $X$. For example $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be seen as a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the points where the third coordinate is $0$. The $\tilde{g}$ in this case will be the standard scalar on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (Note we are identifying the tangent plane of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with itself)